# bootstrap icons needs to be adjust in <textarea> <input type="text">

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to stackoverflow and bootstrap - please help me

I want to adjust two same icons parallel in an input field like in below image:

my desired result is as following:
[image]

note: the structure of HTML will be remain same

```css
.inptRelative {
    position: relative
      }

.inptAbsolute {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group-sm">
      
       <label>Line of Business</label>
       <div class="inptRelative">
     <a href="#" class="inptAbsolute glyphicon glyphicon-list"></a>
           <a href="#" class="inptAbsolute glyphicon glyphicon-list"></a>
     <input type="text" id="myID" value="">
    </div>  
      
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to this code

```css
.form-horizontal .has-feedback .form-control-feedback:last-child {
    right: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-5" for="inputSuccess2">my desired result is as following:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-5" for="inputSuccess2">my desired result is as following:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-5" for="inputSuccess2">my desired result is as following:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-5" for="inputSuccess2">my desired result is as following:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

you can set width as per your need

Comment: Kapil - Its not given me the desired result - Please use mine HTML, Its working fine. What i want is: give some breathing space between two icons. Right now the are overlapped to each-other.

Comment: @Waqas please check answer i updated it as per your requirement

Comment: Your answer is correct if I have to use only once. But I have thousands of rows like above in my whole project. I don't think so writing inline CSS is a smart way.

Comment: I need a solution using above mentioned HTML with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use input-group.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form role = "form" style = "padding: 100px 100px 10px;">
      
      <div class = "input-group">
         <input type = "text" class =" form-control">
         <span class = "input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
      </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: your solution is perfect. But as i said I can't change HTML, I need the solution with given source because its already used in project hundred of times so I do not want to change the source HTML. Any idea with CSS??